# Return value after Promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How I can return value from renderRedirect function after Promise.all?
This is my dispatch actions:

```
 this.props.getChildrens(),
 this.props.getTeachers(),
 this.props.getTeachers()
```

renderRedirect function:

```
renderRedirect = async () => {
   Promise.all([
     this.props.getChildrens(),
     this.props.getTeachers(),
     this.props.getTeachers()
    ]).then(() => {
      return 'test';
    });
  };
```

In my compontent I console.log `renderRedirect` function and here is output:

```
console.log(this.renderRedirect())
Promise {<resolved>: undefined}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return `Promise.all`.

```
renderRedirect = () => {
   // added return keyword
   return Promise.all([
     this.props.getChildrens(),
     this.props.getTeachers(),
     this.props.getTeachers()
    ]).then(() => {
      return 'test';
    });
  };
```

But you shoudl also notice that `console.log(this.renderRedirect())` still don't work because you need to `await` for the result of the promise.

You should do something like:

```
let result = await this.renderRedirect()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Now my console.log output Promise {<pending>}

Comment: @PawełBaca just check the edit, you need to await for the result to `console.log` it

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

1. You need to either `return` the result of calling `Promise.all`'s `then` handler, or use a concise function body so it's implicitly returned.
2. If you're going to make `renderRedirect` `async`, it would be more idiomatic to use `await`.
3. You're outputting the promise from `renderRedirect`. You need to **consume** that promise, not output it.

To deal with #1 and #2, either:

```
// Concise arrow function, not `async`
renderRedirect = () => Promise.all([
     this.props.getChildrens(),
     this.props.getTeachers(),
     this.props.getTeachers()
    ]).then(() => {
      return 'test';
    });
```

or

```
// `async` function
renderRedirect = async () => {
    await Promise.all([
     this.props.getChildrens(),
     this.props.getTeachers(),
     this.props.getTeachers()
    ]);
    return 'test';
};
```

To deal with #3:

```
this.renderRedirect().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

or if that code is in an `async` function:

```
console.log(await this.renderRedirect());
```